# How to make emacs default keys works in non english keyboard layout

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I need to know easy way to make **Emacs** default key bindings works out of the box or with minimal change at system with several **keyboard layouts**. For example I taught students and type in English and Russian on my Fedora machine and out of the box experience nice and easy only with English layout with Russian layout **default bindings not working** and I have to switch to English layout and back. Same problem on Windows 10 machine in Emacs. Please help me to show beauty of Emacs in any language to my students.

Comment: This question is probably more suited to emacs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with Emacs, always use the English layout on the system level, but switch to any Emacs' input-method you like. That way, all the keyboard shortcuts still work, but when typing, you insert characters of a different layout.